# What MOSFET is needed?

Tags: mosfet

I'm working with a motor at 350 W, 36 V DC, and 13 A current. On the MOSFET info sheet, it says it should be able to handle all of this. I just want to confirm before losing buying as to not break the MOSFET and the motor.

Here is the link https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/IRFS3107-7PPBF/IRFS3107-7PPBF-ND/1982966.

I also have a few more questions about MOSFETs:

1. What does the FET type mean, it says N-Channel, but what does that mean?
2. Why are they so cheap compared to other electronics?
3. Do I need a heatsink and if yes, what type?

Comment: Questions #1 and #2 are not really related to your main question so should be asked in a separate question (they might already have been answered on the site, so search first).

Comment: That's 468 watts and not `350 watts`.

Comment: A $5 mosfet won't feel so cheap any more after the 5th one you've melted. I recommend starting with cheaper parts of you're learning electronics. ;)

Comment: @Andyaka Perhaps, these values are max "working" specifications?

Comment: @Andyaka 350W can be the mechanical power the motor is capable of outputting. That gives an efficiency of 75% which seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: $5 really isn't that cheap for a MOSFET unless we're talking about a SiC one. Most of the power FETs I've used in designs are about $1, in some cases substantially less.

Comment: Clarity (not confusion and guess work) is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Based on 1 and 2 (especially 1), I will only address part 3.

You do need a heat sink, and any heat sink which has a sufficiently low thermal resistance will do. That FET package is intended to be used to mount the FET by soldering to a pc board - one which is sized properly for heat conduction.

However, it's clear that you don't have a clue what you're doing, and I cannot recommend that you keep at it. Start small, with a lower-current load, like a 12 or 24-volt, 50-watt incandescent bulb. For this you can use a FET with a TO220 package and an appropriate heat sink. This will let you get some experience with gate drivers and flyback diodes. What you propose doing is fairly straightforward, but at your current level of knowledge is almost certain to end badly.

Answer (score 2):

As @null said, questions 1 and 2 deserve their own posts but briefly:

N-channel refers to how charge/current moves inside the transistor and has a bearing on how the transistor is controlled.

They're cheap because bare devices are usually a small portion of finished goods that include PCB design, assembly, testing, marketing, distribution, overhead, etc.

Now on to the meat of your question: 13 A going through a 2.6 mOhm device will generate about 440 mW.  The junction to ambient thermal resistance is 40 C/W so your junction will heat up about 18C.  Since the maximum junction temperature is 175C, you are well within limits unless you're running it at 150C ambient.

However, the figure for thermal resistance on the datasheet has a note (7) which states that the 40 C/W figure is applicable *when the device is mounted on 1 square inch of FR4* and further directs you to AN-994.  AN-994 has a table that lists thermal resistances for various packages and footprint sizes (mounting your device on a huge pad is essentially a heatsink) and 40 C/W is nowhere to be found for your device's package (D2PAK) but 40 looks to be about the average of the typical and maximum resistances for the minimum and modified minimum footprints, *not* the 1 square inch footprint, so the datasheet and app note need to get their stories straight.

What does all this mean for you?  Since, from the app note, the maximum thermal resistance of the minimum footprint is 47.7 C/W, your worst case thermal rise is only 21 C which is still far, far from the max junction temperature, you shouldn't have to worry about heatsinking or carving out a huge copper area.  It's a lot of work to find out you don't really need to do anything but the process is good to be familiar with.

Comment: From what you said, I take it as this is more powerful than I need it to be. Is it okay to be overkill or is it better to just get a MOSFET just barely enough for the application?

Comment: No, the quoted Id - in this case, 260A - is to be taken with a large, economy sized grain of salt.  You might be able to get away with an RDSon of 10 mOhm or so but remember that device life drops with increasing temperature so you want everything to run as cool as possible.  And of course you haven't said anything about the control you're trying to implement with this device.  On-off is probably fine, but for anything fancier you'd want to take a hard look at the dynamic characteristics to make sure you're not going to run into any problems there.